# Module not found after explicitly adding package dir to sys.path at runtime

Tags: python

Python cannot find 'mypackage' in this scenario:

Tree:

```
- myproject
    - mypackage
        - __init__.py
        - mymodule.py
    - tests
        - test.py
```

Contents of `test.py`

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('.')
sys.path.append(p.absolute())

import mypackage                 # ModuleNotFoundError
from mypackage import mymodule   # ModuleNotFoundError
```

I also printed all the entries from sys.path, where `myproject` is included.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**

I am running python from the `myproject` folder, so the '.' technically works, but I take the point that it's probably not how you should do it. The problem however, seems to have been sys.path not handling a Path object? The solution was string conversion in this case.

Comment: Where do you run the python interpreter from? What did you put in `__init__` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correctly referencing the file, because '.' means the current working directory, use this instead:

```
p = str(Path(Path(__file__).parent.absolute()).parent.absolute())
sys.path.insert(0, p)
```

Comment: It seems what solved the problem was the string conversion. It was puzzling, as the absolute directory was the same with all suggested approaches, including Path('.'), but yes I understand that of course depends on the folder where Python is run from. I suppose sys.path does not deal well with Path objects, but if you print sys.path, it still shows you a generic path.

Answer (score 1):

The dot in `p = Path('.')` just refers to whatever is the current working directory. It may not be the right directory to allow importing `mypackage`.

To inject the correct location it could be `p = Path(__file__).parent.parent` instead. But the correct solution here is actually not to append in `sys.path` at all, it's to [install your package in development mode](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-editable) for running the tests. This links your code into site-packages dir, which is already on `sys.path`, in the more usual way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of development mode. I will definitely look into that.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

in `__init__.py`

```
from .mymodule import *
```

Ensure myproject folder absolute path is in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable
eg in unix/linux:

```
export PYTHONPATH=path_to_my_project
```

or in windows:
you can create a batch like this one (place in myproject)

```
@ echo off
echo setting PYTHONPATH to %~dp0
setx PYTHONPATH %~dp0
pause
```